# Filter data and paste a value of that data into another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, filter

i've got a complicated question...
I've imported data from a .csv file into a worksheet(Imported Data). Now in a different worksheet(Import Function) I use a button as macro to filter out certain data. The filter depends on the data filled in at Cell A2, Cell B2 , Cell C2 (These filters are filled in by the user of excel). If these filters match a row in worksheet(Imported Data), then these values should be pasted on another worksheet. How do I do this? These filters in A2,B2 and C2 match the A,B,C in the other worksheet

Thx in advance..

In reply, I now have the code:

```
Sub FilterButton()
If MsgBox("Are you sure the fields 'Collection' and 'System' are filled in?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Sort function") = vbYes Then
    'If vbYesNo = Yes Then'

Dim ws1, ws2, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim filter1, filter2, filter3 As String
Dim lrow As Double

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import") 'this contains the filters
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Imported Data") 'this contains the text file
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test") ' this is the destination

With ws1
    filter1 = "=" & .Range("A2").Value
    filter2 = "=" & .Range("B2").Value
    filter3 = "=" & .Range("C2").Value
End With

With ws2
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With .Range("A1:G" & lrow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filter1
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=filter2
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=filter3
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
        ws3.Cells(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
End With

.AutoFilterMode = False

End With

End If

End Sub
```

My search criteria(A2,B2,C2 from ws1 match those of ws2(A2,B2,C2) however it isn'pasted on ws3? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hi, change this line `ws3.Cells(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row + 1, 1)` to this `ws3.Cells(ws3.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row + 1, 1)`. I was in a hurry last time that I missed this. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

Dim ws1, ws2, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim filter1, filter2, filter3 As String
Dim lrow As Double


Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'this contains the text file
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 'this contains the filters
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")' this is the destination

With ws2
    filter1 = "=" & .Range("A2").Value
    filter2 = "=" & .Range("B2").Value
    filter3 = "=" & .Range("C2").Value
End With

With ws1
    lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With .Range("A1:O" & lrow)
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=filter1
        .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=filter2
        .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=filter3
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
        ws3.Cells(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
End With

.AutoFilterMode = False

End With

End Sub
```

I just assumed the number of columns (A to O)
I just assumed the field numbers that you need to filter. (5, 8, 14)
Change it based on your needs.
Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying some of my own findings out now :)! Got some error though i'll let you know the solution